# PHP variable breaks page in WooCommerce theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was working on displaying the discount percentage in the category cart. It was working fine until I added the count to actually calculate the percentage based on the regular and sale price. Whenever I add that line of code specifically, the page layout also breaks... and I literally have no idea why.

Below is the mentioned piece of code. **The $discount line breaks the page layout.**

```
<?php 
$product_category = array(
  'category' => array($category->slug),
  'orderby'  => 'name',
);

$products = wc_get_products($product_category);
$regular_price = $products[0]->regular_price;
$sale_price = $products[0]->sale_price;
$discount = (($sale_price - $regular_price) * 100) / $regular_price);
?>
```

Comment: It happened to me a lot when trying to display the variations on the shop page. Are you sure regular price and sale price is defined? that they won't return a "null" value? maybe you should add an "if" in case of a "null".

Comment: @Syntax_Error I've changed it to the numbers themselves now instead of the vars, but it still breaks the page unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you're missing a bracket. 2 opening on the left, but you have 3 closing on the right

Comment: Check your [error log](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/). You may find more details about the issue there.

Comment: @Syntax_Error Damn, it was actually a combination of the two lol. After I removed the extra closing bracket it worked with the numbers, but also in some cases the vars were actually null (which I thought would never happen) that broke the page. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined variables or $regular_price can be zero (and you get division by zero error).

Define all prices variables that may not exist with:
$price = !empty($price) ? $price : 0;

Make sure you don't get division by zero in last line.